# Как избежать конфликта символов при загрузки динамической библиотеки?

Tags: c++, g++

Есть библиотека `libA.so` в которой есть класс `MyClass` и есть библиотека `libB.so` в которой тоже есть класс с тем же именем `MyClass`. Класс не экспортируется, используется только внутри соответствующих библиотек. Эти библиотеки загружаются динамически. Проблема в том, что, если первой была загружена библиотека `libA.so`, то и в библиотеке `libB.so` будет использоваться класс из `libA.so`.

Файл B.cpp в библиотеке libB.so

```
class MyClass
{
    void func() { std::cout << "libB"; }
}
```

Файл A.cpp в библиотеке libA.so

```
class MyClass
{
    void func() { std::cout << "libA"; }
}
```

Всегда будет выводится `libA`.

Можно ли избавится от этого без переименования классов и добавления namespace'ов?

Компилятор g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Интерфейсы классов полностью идентичны? Хорошо бы добавить кода в вопрос. Из идей пока: если обе либы не нужны одновременно, то можно выгружать первую до загрузки второй.

Comment: Да интерфейсы классов полностью идентичны, и библиотеки нужны одновременно.

Comment: Но под в VisualStudio такой проблемы нет, неужели g++ нельзя задать соответствующих настроек?

Comment: Я неправильно понял вопрос. Если нигде в публичный доступ ни один из этих типов не выходит, то мои предыдущие комментарии не актуальны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если функции/классы не экспортируются и используются в библиотеках локально, то извне никто и не должен знать их названия. Варианты:

1. Флаг для того, чтобы скрыть имена всех символов: `-fvisibility=hidden`. Тогда отдельные экспортируемые функции нужно помечать как `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`
2. Помечать скрываемые отдельно атрибутом `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`

Я использую первый вариант с вспомогательным макросом:

```
#define LIB_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
LIB_EXPORT int SomeExportedFunction(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

---

P.S. Сталкивался с подобной проблемой, когда у двух библиотек были идентичные функции `init` из-за чего дважды инициалазировалась одна библиотека.

Comment: Но ведь если нельзя добавить `namespace`, то и атрибуты не получится внести в имеющиеся библиотеки.

Comment: @alexolut Я предположил, что это связано не с недоступностью исходников, а с нежеланием лишний раз задумываться. Это разумно - почему разработчик библиотеки A должен думать, что придёт B и напишет такую же гадость?

Comment: Хороший ответ; судя по всему, этого поведения можно добиться и без модификации кода. Посмотрите на [export maps](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1372)